# Can't install Qemu on Debian 9

Tags: debian, apt, qemu

I am trying to install qemu on my debian/stretch machine, but when I run `sudo apt install qemu`, I get the following message:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
qemu : Depends: qemu-system (>= 1:2.8+dfsg-6+deb9u4)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I've tried installing qemu-system, but then I get a similar message, that qemu-system depends on more packages in the form of qemu-system-*, which all depend on the same library, which ultimately depends on `libslang2`. But when I try to install that, it tells me the following:

```
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  ncurses-base ncurses-term rxvt-unicode
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libslang2
WARNING: The following essential packages will be removed.
This should NOT be done unless you know exactly what you are doing!
  ncurses-base
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 3 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 503 kB of archives.
After this operation, 6,458 kB disk space will be freed.
You are about to do something potentially harmful.
To continue type in the phrase 'Yes, do as I say!'
 ?]
```

Which I of course won't do. I suspect that somehow I've messed up my apt-get, since similar stuff has happened the past days, but I was always able to resolve it.

EDIT:
So, to answer the comments, you guys posted:

To get the second output, I simply typed `sudo apt install libslang2`

I tried updating/upgrading several times, and I checked if my `/etc/apt/sources.list` had any errors aswell, also tried `apt --fix-broken install` and `apt install -f`

Lastly, when I type the `apt -o` command, I get the following:

```
Starting pkgProblemResolver with broken count: 2
Starting 2 pkgProblemResolver with broken count: 2
Investigating (0) ncurses-base:amd64 < 6.1+20181013-1 @ii mK Ib >
Broken ncurses-base:amd64 Breaks on libslang2:amd64 < none -> 2.3.1-5 @un uN > (< 2.3.1a-3)
  Considering libslang2:amd64 1 as a solution to ncurses-base:amd64 5100
  Added libslang2:amd64 to the remove list
  Fixing ncurses-base:amd64 via keep of libslang2:amd64
Investigating (0) libcaca0:amd64 < none -> 0.99.beta19-2+b2 @un uN Ib >
Broken libcaca0:amd64 Depends on libslang2:amd64 < none | 2.3.1-5 @un uH > (>= 2.2.4)
  Considering libslang2:amd64 1 as a solution to libcaca0:amd64 5
  Holding Back libcaca0:amd64 rather than change libslang2:amd64
Investigating (0) libsdl1.2debian:amd64 < none -> 1.2.15+dfsg1-4 @un uN Ib >
Broken libsdl1.2debian:amd64 Depends on libcaca0:amd64 < none | 0.99.beta19-2+b2 @un
uH > (>= 0.99.beta17-1)
  Considering libcaca0:amd64 5 as a solution to libsdl1.2debian:amd64 5
  Holding Back libsdl1.2debian:amd64 rather than change libcaca0:amd64
Investigating (0) qemu-system-sparc:amd64 < none -> 1:2.8+dfsg-6+deb9u4 @un uN Ib >
Broken qemu-system-sparc:amd64 Depends on libsdl1.2debian:amd64 < none | 1.2.15+dfsg1-4 @un uH > (>= 1.2.11)
  Considering libsdl1.2debian:amd64 5 as a solution to qemu-system-sparc:amd64 0
  Holding Back qemu-system-sparc:amd64 rather than change libsdl1.2debian:amd64
Investigating (0) qemu-system:amd64 < none -> 1:2.8+dfsg-6+deb9u4 @un uN Ib >
Broken qemu-system:amd64 Depends on qemu-system-sparc:amd64 < none | 1:2.8+dfsg-6+deb9u4 @un uH >
  Considering qemu-system-sparc:amd64 0 as a solution to qemu-system:amd64 0
  Holding Back qemu-system:amd64 rather than change qemu-system-sparc:amd64
Investigating (0) qemu-system-arm:amd64 < none -> 1:2.8+dfsg-6+deb9u4 @un uN Ib >
Broken qemu-system-arm:amd64 Depends on libsdl1.2debian:amd64 < none | 1.2.15+dfsg1-4 @un uH > (>= 1.2.11)
Considering libsdl1.2debian:amd64 5 as a solution to qemu-system-arm:amd64 0
  Holding Back qemu-system-arm:amd64 rather than change libsdl1.2debian:amd64
Investigating (0) qemu-system-ppc:amd64 < none -> 1:2.8+dfsg-6+deb9u4 @un uN Ib >
Broken qemu-system-ppc:amd64 Depends on libsdl1.2debian:amd64 < none | 1.2.15+dfsg1-4 @un uH > (>= 1.2.11)
  Considering libsdl1.2debian:amd64 5 as a solution to qemu-system-ppc:amd64 0
  Holding Back qemu-system-ppc:amd64 rather than change libsdl1.2debian:amd64
Investigating (0) qemu-system-misc:amd64 < none -> 1:2.8+dfsg-6+deb9u4 @un uN Ib >
Broken qemu-system-misc:amd64 Depends on libsdl1.2debian:amd64 < none | 1.2.15+dfsg1-4 @un uH > (>= 1.2.11)
  Considering libsdl1.2debian:amd64 5 as a solution to qemu-system-misc:amd64 0
  Holding Back qemu-system-misc:amd64 rather than change libsdl1.2debian:amd64
Investigating (0) qemu-system-mips:amd64 < none -> 1:2.8+dfsg-6+deb9u4 @un uN Ib >
Broken qemu-system-mips:amd64 Depends on libsdl1.2debian:amd64 < none | 1.2.15+dfsg1-4 @un uH > (>= 1.2.11)
  Considering libsdl1.2debian:amd64 5 as a solution to qemu-system-mips:amd64 0
  Holding Back qemu-system-mips:amd64 rather than change libsdl1.2debian:amd64
Investigating (0) qemu-system-x86:amd64 < none -> 1:2.8+dfsg-6+deb9u4 @un uN Ib >
Broken qemu-system-x86:amd64 Depends on libsdl1.2debian:amd64 < none | 1.2.15+dfsg1-4 @un uH > (>= 1.2.11)
  Considering libsdl1.2debian:amd64 5 as a solution to qemu-system-x86:amd64 0
  Holding Back qemu-system-x86:amd64 rather than change libsdl1.2debian:amd64
Investigating (1) qemu:amd64 < none -> 1:2.8+dfsg-6+deb9u4 @un puN Ib >
Broken qemu:amd64 Depends on qemu-system:amd64 < none | 1:2.8+dfsg-6+deb9u4 @un uH >
(>= 1:2.8+dfsg-6+deb9u4)
  Considering qemu-system:amd64 0 as a solution to qemu:amd64 9999
  Re-Instated libslang2:amd64
  Re-Instated libcaca0:amd64
  Re-Instated libsdl1.2debian:amd64
  Re-Instated qemu-system-arm:amd64
  Re-Instated qemu-system-mips:amd64
  Re-Instated qemu-system-ppc:amd64
  Re-Instated qemu-system-sparc:amd64
  Re-Instated qemu-system-x86:amd64
  Re-Instated qemu-system-misc:amd64
  Re-Instated qemu-system:amd64
Investigating (1) ncurses-base:amd64 < 6.1+20181013-1 @ii mK Ib >
Broken ncurses-base:amd64 Breaks on libslang2:amd64 < none -> 2.3.1-5 @un uN > (< 2.3.1a-3)
  Considering libslang2:amd64 1 as a solution to ncurses-base:amd64 5100
  Added libslang2:amd64 to the remove list
  Fixing ncurses-base:amd64 via keep of libslang2:amd64
Investigating (1) libcaca0:amd64 < none -> 0.99.beta19-2+b2 @un uN Ib >
Broken libcaca0:amd64 Depends on libslang2:amd64 < none | 2.3.1-5 @un uH > (>= 2.2.4)
  Considering libslang2:amd64 1 as a solution to libcaca0:amd64 5
  Holding Back libcaca0:amd64 rather than change libslang2:amd64
Investigating (1) libsdl1.2debian:amd64 < none -> 1.2.15+dfsg1-4 @un uN Ib >
Broken libsdl1.2debian:amd64 Depends on libcaca0:amd64 < none | 0.99.beta19-2+b2 @un
uH > (>= 0.99.beta17-1)
  Considering libcaca0:amd64 5 as a solution to libsdl1.2debian:amd64 5
  Holding Back libsdl1.2debian:amd64 rather than change libcaca0:amd64
Investigating (1) qemu-system-sparc:amd64 < none -> 1:2.8+dfsg-6+deb9u4 @un uN Ib >
Broken qemu-system-sparc:amd64 Depends on libsdl1.2debian:amd64 < none | 1.2.15+dfsg1-4 @un uH > (>= 1.2.11)
  Considering libsdl1.2debian:amd64 5 as a solution to qemu-system-sparc:amd64 0
  Holding Back qemu-system-sparc:amd64 rather than change libsdl1.2debian:amd64
Investigating (1) qemu-system:amd64 < none -> 1:2.8+dfsg-6+deb9u4 @un uN Ib >
Broken qemu-system:amd64 Depends on qemu-system-sparc:amd64 < none | 1:2.8+dfsg-6+deb9u4 @un uH >
  Considering qemu-system-sparc:amd64 0 as a solution to qemu-system:amd64 0
  Holding Back qemu-system:amd64 rather than change qemu-system-sparc:amd64
Investigating (1) qemu-system-arm:amd64 < none -> 1:2.8+dfsg-6+deb9u4 @un uN Ib >
Broken qemu-system-arm:amd64 Depends on libsdl1.2debian:amd64 < none | 1.2.15+dfsg1-4 @un uH > (>= 1.2.11)
  Considering libsdl1.2debian:amd64 5 as a solution to qemu-system-arm:amd64 0
  Holding Back qemu-system-arm:amd64 rather than change libsdl1.2debian:amd64
Investigating (1) qemu-system-ppc:amd64 < none -> 1:2.8+dfsg-6+deb9u4 @un uN Ib >
Broken qemu-system-ppc:amd64 Depends on libsdl1.2debian:amd64 < none | 1.2.15+dfsg1-4 @un uH > (>= 1.2.11)
  Considering libsdl1.2debian:amd64 5 as a solution to qemu-system-ppc:amd64 0
  Holding Back qemu-system-ppc:amd64 rather than change libsdl1.2debian:amd64
Investigating (1) qemu-system-misc:amd64 < none -> 1:2.8+dfsg-6+deb9u4 @un uN Ib >
Broken qemu-system-misc:amd64 Depends on libsdl1.2debian:amd64 < none | 1.2.15+dfsg1-4 @un uH > (>= 1.2.11)
  Considering libsdl1.2debian:amd64 5 as a solution to qemu-system-misc:amd64 0
  Holding Back qemu-system-misc:amd64 rather than change libsdl1.2debian:amd64
Investigating (1) qemu-system-mips:amd64 < none -> 1:2.8+dfsg-6+deb9u4 @un uN Ib >
Broken qemu-system-mips:amd64 Depends on libsdl1.2debian:amd64 < none | 1.2.15+dfsg1-4 @un uH > (>= 1.2.11)
  Considering libsdl1.2debian:amd64 5 as a solution to qemu-system-mips:amd64 0
  Holding Back qemu-system-mips:amd64 rather than change libsdl1.2debian:amd64
Investigating (1) qemu-system-x86:amd64 < none -> 1:2.8+dfsg-6+deb9u4 @un uN Ib >
Broken qemu-system-x86:amd64 Depends on libsdl1.2debian:amd64 < none | 1.2.15+dfsg1-4 @un uH > (>= 1.2.11)
Considering libsdl1.2debian:amd64 5 as a solution to qemu-system-x86:amd64 0
  Holding Back qemu-system-x86:amd64 rather than change libsdl1.2debian:amd64
Investigating (2) qemu:amd64 < none -> 1:2.8+dfsg-6+deb9u4 @un puN Ib >
Broken qemu:amd64 Depends on qemu-system:amd64 < none | 1:2.8+dfsg-6+deb9u4 @un uH >
(>= 1:2.8+dfsg-6+deb9u4)
  Considering qemu-system:amd64 0 as a solution to qemu:amd64 9999
  Considering qemu-system:i386 -1 as a solution to qemu:amd64 9999
  Re-Instated libaio1:i386
  Re-Instated libbluetooth3:i386
  Re-Instated libbrlapi0.6:i386
  Re-Instated libnspr4:i386
  Re-Instated libnss3:i386
  Re-Instated libcacard0:i386
  Re-Instated libfdt1:i386
    Reinst Failed early because of libtinfo5:i386
    Reinst Failed because of libncursesw5:i386
    Reinst Failed because of qemu-system-arm:i386
Investigating (2) libnspr4:amd64 < 2:4.20-1 @ii mK Ib >
Broken libnspr4:amd64 Breaks on libnspr4:i386 < none -> 2:4.12-6 @un uN Ib > (!= 2:4.20-1)
  Considering libnspr4:i386 0 as a solution to libnspr4:amd64 16
  Added libnspr4:i386 to the remove list
  Fixing libnspr4:amd64 via keep of libnspr4:i386
Investigating (2) libnss3:amd64 < 2:3.39-1 @ii mK Ib >
Broken libnss3:amd64 Breaks on libnss3:i386 < none -> 2:3.26.2-1.1+deb9u1 @un uN Ib > (!= 2:3.39-1)
  Considering libnss3:i386 0 as a solution to libnss3:amd64 11
  Added libnss3:i386 to the remove list
  Fixing libnss3:amd64 via keep of libnss3:i386
Investigating (2) libcacard0:i386 < none -> 1:2.5.0-3 @un uN Ib >
Broken libcacard0:i386 Depends on libnspr4:i386 < none | 2:4.12-6 @un uH > (>= 2:4.9-2~)
  Considering libnspr4:i386 16 as a solution to libcacard0:i386 0
  Holding Back libcacard0:i386 rather than change libnspr4:i386
Investigating (3) qemu:amd64 < none -> 1:2.8+dfsg-6+deb9u4 @un puN Ib >
Broken qemu:amd64 Depends on qemu-system:amd64 < none | 1:2.8+dfsg-6+deb9u4 @un uH >
(>= 1:2.8+dfsg-6+deb9u4)
  Considering qemu-system:amd64 0 as a solution to qemu:amd64 9999
  Considering qemu-system:i386 -1 as a solution to qemu:amd64 9999
Done
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I can't read a solution out of that, only that its trying different packages but all of them would ultimately break something. But its the first time Ive seen this command.

Comment: Please update question to show, what you type to get 2nd error message?

Comment: "E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages."  Have you fixed broken packages?  Did you try update and upgrade?

Comment: What does `apt -o Debug::pkgProblemResolver=yes install qemu` output? (Please [edit] your question to add the output.)

Answer (score 0):

I would:

```
apt-get install synaptic "if not installed already"
```

- Then run it
- Find qemu
- If it is installed mark for complete removal
- Then apply
- Reboot
- Run synaptic
- Reinstall qemu
- Make sure that synaptic reports no errors or broken packages
- If errors or broken packages exist use synaptic to find solutions

Done